# Get latest distinct value of a field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to query the **latest** + **distinct** name.

I got the distinct part to work, but they're not the latest. I'm not sure how to do that in Laravel.

---

## I’ve tried

```
$localDevices = Device::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('mac')->get();

        $localDeviceName = [];
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($localDevices as $localDevice) {
            foreach ($devices as $device) {
                if($localDevice->mac == $device->device_mac ){
                    $localDeviceName[$i]['name'] = $localDevice->name;
                    $localDeviceName[$i]['mac'] = $device->device_mac;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

---

## Database

[image]

---

## I got

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Apple Watch"
    "img" => "/images/photos/devices/apple-watch.jpg"
    "mac" => "080027E2FC7D"
  ]
]
```

I want it to show ps4 because it is the **latest**.

---

## Try #2

I tried update my

`orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` to `orderBy('created_at', 'asc')`

I got the **same** result.

---

## Try #3

I tried placing `orderBy` after `groupBy`

`Device::groupBy('mac')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

I got the **same** result.

---

What can I try next?

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument in `orderBy()` should be `desc` not `dsc`?

Comment: Same result even change it to `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`. I'll update my post.

Comment: Little odd, your approach is correct, it should be working. When I use `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` in my queries, the expected result is given. How about removing the `groupBy()` constraint all together, does it order correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a `groupBy` on your mac value which isn't unique, your Apple watch and PS4 have the same **mac**, mysql first groups by then orders your grouped results. That's why you are always getting Apple watch.

What you want is to fetch the latest record from each group and for that you might write a **Raw query**, check this [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)